# Access external API from Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

Is it possible to use an external API from Google Earth Engine?

I'm new to GEE and scoping potential application for a project. Briefly we have an API wrapper for a process based model. We want to:

1. define areas in GEE which extract relevant data from GEE datasets.
2. use data from the defined area to parameterise the model, posting the parameterisation data to the API.
3. map the returned API response in GEE.

The model is written in Fortran and while we could recode into JS to run within GEE, we would prefer to keep it decoupled.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to access an external API (e.g. a FORTRAN program) within GEE's environments. What you can do is leverage GEE as much as possible to do the pre-processing and export only what you need for each model run.

You could also take a look at the latest GEE integrations with other projects
https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/sustainability/new-earth-engine-features-support-geospatial-integrations

e.g., perhaps you can build an xarray/dask wrapper for your FORTRAN model in python with the help of [xee](https://github.com/google/Xee).